# Understanding first cousin and grandson/grandfather relationships at 23andMe

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, 23andme

I have 2 first cousin matches on 23andme.. both named ‘John’. Their relationship is listed as grandson/grandfather. With that age difference and relationship they both cannot be my cousin. I’m adopted and had a great life this just has me stumped .. like a word problem from HS. Both 19 segments and 10.8% and 7.43%...

Comment: Perhaps review https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12351/19 if you have not already.

Answer (score 3):

It's often difficult to ascertain relationships precisely from individual pair-wise matches (or even from 2 of them), in the absence of family tree knowledge.  From the [DNA Painter Shared CM tool](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4), one relationship that fits the numbers is if the "grandfather" is your great-grandfather, and the "grandson" your first cousin once removed (1C1R).  But, I suspect that doesn't fit the actual scenario.

It's also possible that there's some other factor that causes 23AndMe to infer the grandparent/grandchild relationship for these two persons, when they may actually be, e.g. uncle/nephew (they look very similar from numbers alone).

Best bet - contact these two members, explain your situation, and find out how they're actually related (better than trying to guess from match numbers).